# Set limit email sending count

Tags: node.js, email, web-hosting, nodemailer

I've implemented mail function by using `nodemailer`.
I am going implement set limit feature when send multiple mails in one time, but I am confused and don't know how to implement it.

I going to set sending limit per minute so that send 7 mails per minute maximum.
How can I implement it in node.js

I've considered some ways for it.
1. cronjob
  Save email address to database and cronjob get a mail & send one by one every 8 - 9 sec. so that can send only 6 or 7 mails per minute.
2. setTimeout.
  If I have to send 100 mails one time, I can put them to queue and send one by one with  delay.

Which way is correct? If these ways are all incorrect, please give me the correct way.

Thanks.

Comment: Please show us what have you tried in form of code in order to help out. [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @ambianBeign  Until now, I haven't started coding. I haven't any concept. can you please suggest the correct way ?

Comment: Okay! Thats subjective. IMHO I have mostly tried to avoid implementing logics on `setTimeout()` and especially `setInterval()`. And cron are cleaner way to go about because that's what they do. Having said that `nodemailer` comes with setting config to use pool and rate limiting, please do check out if it can help in achieving this. [Link](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/pooled/)

Answer (score -1):

I think i would be better to store count of mails sent inside the database with a timestamp of first mail then whenever a new request comes compare current time with the timestamp in data base if difference is more than 7 minutes just allow `nodemailer` to send the mail or else show the error.